# iOS app crashes when tapping "Sign in with Google" in Expo-managed app

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, crash, google-signin

I'm encountering an issue where my Expo-managed app crashes on iOS when attempting to sign in with Google. However, on Android, the functionality works perfectly fine. I'm unable to use Xcode as my app is managed by Expo, and I'm not utilizing the sponsored version.

Here's a snippet of my app.json configuration:

```
"plugins": [
    "expo-apple-authentication",
    [
        "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin",
        {
            "iosUrlScheme": "com.googleusercontent.apps.xxx-xxx"
        }
    ]
],
"ios": {
    "bundleIdentifier": "myapp",
    "infoPList": {
        "CFBundleURLTypes": [{"CFBundleURLSchemes":["com.googleusercontent.apps.xxx-xxx"]}],
        "UIRequiresFullScreen": true,
        ...
    }
}
```

And here's a portion of my GoogleLogin.js file:

```
const SignIn = async () => {
    try {
        GoogleSignin.configure({
            webClientId: "xxx-xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
            androidClientId: "xxx-xxx.googleusercontent.com",
            iosClientId: "xxx-xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
        });
        await GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices();
        const userInfo = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
```

Despite the configuration, the app crashes without providing any userInfo, and I'm unable to retrieve any logs. Additionally, I'm not using Expo Go to test.

I'm using the following dependencies:

```
"expo": "~49.0.6"
"react-native": "0.72.6"
"@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "^11.0.0"
```

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions or assistance in resolving this issue. Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

- The issue you're encountering is likely due to the fact that you're using Expo's managed workflow, which doesn't support all native modules out of the box. In this case, the Google Sign-In module you're using is a native module, and it's not compatible with Expo's managed workflow.
- To resolve this issue you have two options

  ```
  Use Expo's bare workflow
  ```
- You can find more information on the bare workflow here https://docs.expo.dev/introduction/managed-vs-bare/
- Use the expo-auth-session and expo-google-app-auth packages.
  You can find more information on these packages here: https://docs.expo.dev/guides/authentication/#google

  ```
  import React from 'react';
  import { Button, Text } from 'react-native';
  import * as Google from 'expo-google-app-auth';
  import * as AuthSession from 'expo-auth-session';

  const App = () => {
   const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = React.useState(null);

   const signIn = async () => {
    try {
      const result = await Google.logInAsync({
        androidClientId: 'YOUR_ANDROID_CLIENT_ID',
        iosClientId: 'YOUR_IOS_CLIENT_ID',
        scopes: ['profile', 'email'],
      });

      if (result.type === 'success') {
        setUserInfo(result.user);
      } else {
        console.log('Google Sign-In failed', result);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error during Google Sign-In', error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {userInfo ? (
        <Text>Welcome, {userInfo.name}!</Text>
      ) : (
        <Button title="Sign in with Google" onPress={signIn} />
      )}
    </React.Fragment>
   );
  };

  export default App;
  ```